# Replace semicolon in @ftime (forfile function) to use in a file name

Tags: ms-dos

As you know you can use the function `forfile`:

```
forfiles /M "fileA" /C "cmd /c copy @path C:\Documents\archives\@fname_ @fdate"
```

I'm trying to use `@ftime`, but it contains `:` which I want to replace with space or "".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For using **`forfile`** and remove **`:`** and also, removing quotes:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_=C:\Documents\archives" && for /f tokens^=1-7 %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%forfiles.exe /M *fileA*.log /C "cmd /C echo @path !_! @fname @fdate @ftime @ext"'
)do && for /f tokens^=^1^ ^delims^=^" %%I in ('echo/%%~i')do set "_L=%%~l_%%~m" && call set "_L=!_L::=!" && (
set "_target=%%~j\_%%~k_!_L!" && call set _target=!_target:^"=!&& cmd /v /c copy "%%~I" "!_target!.%%~o" )

goto :EOF
```

---

- Same code in conventional formatting:

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_=C:\Documents\archives" 

for /f tokens^=1-7 %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%forfiles.exe /M *fileA*.log /C "cmd /C echo @path !_! @fname @fdate @ftime @ext"'
)do for /f tokens^=^1^ ^delims^=^" %%I in ('echo/%%~i')do ( 
    set "_L=%%~l_%%~m"
    call set "_L=!_L::=!"
    set "_target=%%~j\_%%~k_!_L!"
    call set _target=!_target:^"=!
    cmd /v /c copy "%%~I" "!_target!.%%~o"
    )

goto :EOF
```

---

To **`copy`** and **`rename`** the target files with last **modified date/time**, I suggest that you use the **`wmic.exe`** and a looping **`for`** command instead of **`forfiles`**:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir *fileA*.* /b /a:-d /o-d /t:w'
)do set "_F=%%~fi" && for /f "tokens=1 delims=+." %%d in ('
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe datafile where name^="!_F:\=\\!" get "LastModified"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]'
)do set "_d=%%~d" && call copy "%%~fi" "C:\Documents\archives\%%~ni_!_d:~0,4!!_d:~4,2!!_d:~6,2!_!_d:~8,2!.!_d:~10,2!%%~xi"
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

- Same code in conventional formatting:

  ---

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir *fileA*.* /b /a:-d /o-d /t:w')do (
    set "_F=%%~fi" 
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=+." %%d in (
     '%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe datafile where name^="!_F:\=\\!" get "LastModified"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]'
     )do (
     set "_d=%%~d"
     call copy "%%~fi" "C:\Documents\archives\%%~ni_!_d:~0,4!!_d:~4,2!!_d:~6,2!_!_d:~8,2!.!_d:~10,2!%%~xi"
     ))

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

An example of command and output **`wmic`** to get the entire data file:

---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%wmic.exe datafile where name='G:\\SUPER_USER\\Q1525416\\xy-_fileA_yx.log' get * /format:list
```

---

- Outputs:

  ---

```bat
AccessMask=4294967295
Archive=TRUE
Caption=g:\super_user\q1525416\xy-_filea_yx.log
Compressed=FALSE
CompressionMethod=
CreationClassName=CIM_LogicalFile
CreationDate=20200214134852.240000+***
CSCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
CSName=LESMA_MANCA
Description=g:\super_user\q1525416\xy-_filea_yx.log
Drive=g:
EightDotThreeFileName=g:\super_user\q1525416\xy-_fi~1.log
Encrypted=FALSE
EncryptionMethod=
Extension=log
FileName=xy-_fileA_yx
FileSize=973
FileType=Text Document
FSCreationClassName=Win32_FileSystem
FSName=FAT32
Hidden=FALSE
InstallDate=20200214134852.240000+***
InUseCount=
LastAccessed=20200214000000.000000+***
LastModified=20200214130618.000000+***
Manufacturer=
Name=g:\super_user\q1525416\xy-_filea_yx.log
Path=\super_user\q1525416\
Readable=TRUE
Status=OK
System=FALSE
Version=
Writeable=TRUE
```

---

**[WMIC.exe /?](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)**